# Sending data to different tables according to variable value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "wifi" and another table called "bluetooth" on my mysql database
 I have a $string from a form
if the string contains "wifi" I want to set the $tbl_name= to "wifi" , 
else set it to "bluetooth"
then send the data to the appropriate table
I havent found any example, am I doing the right thing ? Yes, I'm new :)

I'm doing this:

```
$xplatform=$_POST['platform'];
echo "made_variables ok";
// Insert data into mysql
//ifstatement decides which table to insert into
if(preg_match('/wifi/',$xplatform))
{
$tbl_name='wifi';
}
else 
{
$tbl_name='bluetooth';
};
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name`(`field1`,`field2`,`f3`)
VALUES('$_POST[numberlat]','$_POST[numberlng]','$_POST[name]','$_POST[website]','$_POST
[message]','$_POST[radius]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[platform]')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
if($_POST['string'] == 'wifi') {
  $tbl_name = 'wifi';
} else {
  $tbl_name = 'bluetooth';
}
```

Use that instead of `preg_match()` because the `preg` functions in PHP are very expensive.